# Left and right derivation of Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, derivation

How can the result of the execution of $ \rightarrow RL$ differ from that of $\rightarrow LR$? In turing machines

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on what you are asking.  Please define all non-standard notation.  What does the notation $\to RL$ mean?

Comment: What did you try? What progress have you made? You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.